# How to get all configured resources in a namespace using Kubernetes API client, NOT kubectl

Tags: kubernetes

I'd like to use a a client external to the Kubernetes cluster to fetch all configured resources in a particular namespace, so the equivalent of the kubectl command below using curl or the fabric8 k8s client.

`kubectl api-resources --verbs=list --namespaced -o name | xargs -n 1 kubectl get --show-kind --ignore-not-found -n <namespace>`

Comment: What did you try already? Can you include [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). No one is going to give you complete solution without contribution from your side.

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/ is a good starting point.